# double To String

Tags: .net

I need a double to string to be displayed with max X chars after the decimal separator.

I tried

```
?string.Format("{0,10}", 1.234567890123456789)
"1,23456789012346"

?string.Format("{0:F10}", 1,234567890123456789)
"1,0000000000"
```

Comment: 1.234567890123456789.ToString("C10", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)//add: using System.Globalization;

Comment: Your second string.Format is malformed, I believe. It seems like you are treating it as a number with a comma decimal-separator (as in some cultures). However, .NET only recognizes the dot separator, so you'll need to turn that into a string and interpret it with the correct Culture (as in @Margus' example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bigger hint:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F1}", Math.Pi)); // Prints 3.1
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F2}", Math.Pi)); // Prints 3.14
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F3}", Math.Pi)); // Prints 3.141
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that this is homework, I'll point you to the relevant documentation instead of giving you the code:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)
- [Composite Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

Note that if you're happy with *exactly* X decimal places, it's relatively easy with a standard numeric format string. If you want *at most* X decimal places (but fewer if possible), you may need to use a custom numeric format string. At least as far as I've seen...

Comment: @serhio: Yup, so you need to read a bit more about what the format string you've tried actually means, as well as the other options...

Comment: I saw it all, but however don't see

Comment: @serhio: Hint - currently you're providing an *alignment*, which specifies a *minimum* width. I doubt that you've read through all of those links... look for *precision* instead of alignment...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875(v=vs.71).aspx) function to format your numbers.  To show a number with 2 decimals use:

```
String.Format("{0.00}",MyNumber);
```

Comment: Then you will want to create the format string dynamically with X number of zeros :D

Answer (score 0):

Jons got the right direction, I use the collection http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ over at csharp-examples as I dont deal with these everyday but atleast once a week (just enough to forget), these snippets should get you what you need.

Comment: I saw already page you give... but there is no option like i ask

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to what the others suggested (`String.Format("{0:0.0000000000}", number)`) for example, if you need to always have 10 decimals after the decimal separator, that the `String.Format` formats the numbers based on the current culture, so in the USA it'll use the `.` as decimal separator, in Europe the `,`. If you need to format a number in a "fixed" "default" culture you can do this: `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.0000000000}", number)`. If you need to format in a specific culture: `String.Format(new CultureInfo("it-IT"), "{0:0.0000000000}"` (this will use Italian Culture).